# Why does creat("foo", S_IRUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH) result in -r--------- permission?

Tags: c, unix

I created a file foo using `creat("foo",S_IRUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH)`.

After the file creation, `ls -l`  shows `-r--------`. Should not the read access for group and others also be set?

Comment: What is your [`umask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html)?

Comment: My umask is 77. Probably this is why the read access is not given to the file.

Comment: if  **umask  is 077** ,then it creates file with read/write permission as **-rw-------** .

Comment: Yes...When i changed the umask 0 then the file was created as expected.